# Programmatically create js file and edit existing js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am working on a React project for a non-profit with the goal to allow them to post articles to viewers on the website. (like Wired.com posts tech articles)

Currently, I am creating a component for each page, then adding that to the React Router route file so it has a URL, then creating a post preview in a few places to link to that new article page (such as on the front page carousel to show recent posts), then finally adding the actual content to the article page (like paragraphs, links, and graphs).

The client now wants to be able to post articles without going thru me, much like a traditional Squarespace/Wordpress site might have setup, but I do not want to backtrack after creating this React site.

I want to try and create something for the client to fit their needs with the current React site. I can imagine how to allow an admin login section that allows the admin to create a post by submitting the title, image URL, and the body text, but two things I am stumped on are how to go about programmatically creating a JS component file (like ArticleName.js) in a specific location in my src directory, and then also editing existing JS files (like adding a route to react router). I would love to get some direction on how to tackle this. Or am I recreating the wheel and is this a use case of when website builders like Wordpress are a better choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're definitely recreating the wheel and given the use case it's in their best interest to use something that exists already.  If you're doing this pro bono and time and cost are not an issue, it'd be a good experience for you and could pad your resume.  If any of those things are an issue, take the off the shelf solution, there's a lot to consider that would be difficult for just one person to do quickly and competently.

Comment: That helps a ton, I will need to talk to the client on the route they want to take, thanks Paul!